# Exception due to CLOB datatype in GSON library

Tags: java, sql, gson, mybatis, clob

I am getting this strange issue while using CLOB datatype and converting it into JSON response but it's giving an error like,

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor declares multiple JSON fields named statement
```

I am using myBatis for fetching data from database and object which myBatis return is

```
[{EMAIL_TEMPLATE_ID=1, CREATED_BY=owner, COMMON_BODY=oracle.sql.CLOB@1d8b47a, COMMON_SUBJECT=This os common subject line in notification table, CREATED_DATE=2020-02-03 00:00:00.0, COMMON_CC_USER=abc@gmail.com, STATUS=pending, NOTIFICATION_ID=1, HAS_ATTACHMENT=y, UPDATED_BY=tester, EXPIRY_DAYS=10, SCHEDULE_TIME=2, COMMON_TO_USER=xyz@gmail.com, UPDATED_DATE=2020-02-03 00:00:00.0, NOTIFICATION_TYPE=dist}]
```

In above Object **COMMON_BODY** is having **CLOB** datatype.

I am storing this object in results variable which is a list of map.

```
List<Map<String,Object>> results  =  session.selectList(id,searchparams);
```

Now when I print results it gives correct results but when I try to convert it into JSON response using gson it gives me error

```
String json = gson.toJson(results);
```

I changed datatype of CLOB to String then it's working fine but when I am using CLOB datatype it gives me exception like

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class oracle.jdbc.driver.Accessor declares multiple JSON fields named statement
```